# She's worth two of him

Tags: numbers

A similar structure to *She's worth two of him* is used in [*Oliver Twist* by Charles Dickens](https://books.google.es/books?id=2A-fTIGpvcUC&lpg=PA280&dq=%22worth%20two%20of%20him%22&hl=es&pg=PA280#v=onepage&q=%22worth%20two%20of%20him%22&f=false).

Is this still grammatical? Is it related to *that makes **two**/?four of us*?

TWO: https://oed.com/oed2/00260784

Comment: 1. It is no use asking about a construction that is "similar" : you should give the original. 2. There is no use linking to a general entry on the OED that is several pages long - English speakers understand "two".  3. When you ask "Is this still grammatical?" what is "this"? What Dickens wrote or the original construction?

Comment: "She's worth two of him" - she is twice as valuable as he is (of more use in particular circumstances, or a better person). Literally, she is of the same value as two people like him.